# Java optimization: storing map.size() in a variable

Tags: java, optimization

In my program (Bayes classifier), I have a lot of calls to the `map.size()` method.

I was wondering if the performance of the program can be optimized by storing the value of `map.size()` in a local variable (or a field).

If so, what would be the right way to store it in a variable?

```
int mapSize = map.size();
```

Below the surface, this will probably just create a pointer to the method (?)

Comment: In most map implementations, size() is O(1), and simply returns the value of a field. Storing it in a variable most probably won't change anything. Don't try random things to optimize your code. Measure (that's hard, but necessary), and then concentrate on the parts that actually take time.

Comment: A `Map` needs to know its `size()` so (in most implementations) it's already sorted internally. Storing it externally means that you'd need to add a whole lot of invalidate/update logic. If your `Map` never changes you can likely reap large benefits from switching to an immutable `Map` implementation. As with all micro-optimisations this is a generalisation, without running microbenchmarks against your code you will never get a definitive answer.

Comment: Which map implementation are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below which is provided in your question would not store a pointer to the method, it stores the value that method returned.

```
int mapSize = map.size();
```

Looking at the `HashMap.size();` method you can see it just returns a local variable, which is causing it to be really fast already:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.
 *
 * @return the number of key-value mappings in this map
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Comment: As both JBNizet and I point out in comments this is an implementation detail and depending on the specific `Map` implementation user the latter half of your answer is potentially false.